# Uncaught exception: Reference error: Db is not defined

Tags: database, mongodb, shell, exception, command

I am new to MongoDb and I am trying to interact with databases using command line interface. However, I am facing the error uncaught exception. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

```
> show dbs
Organization  0.000GB
admin         0.000GB
config        0.000GB
local         0.000GB
> Organizations.dropDatabase()
uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Organizations is not defined :
@(shell):1:1
>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Updated the question. Can you please check it help me if possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look how [dropDatabase](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_drop_database.htm) works.

```
> use Organizations
> db.dropDatabase()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
use Organizations
db.dropDatabase()
```

or

```
db.getSiblingDB("Organizations").dropDatabase()
```